# PHP Dynamically split number into fraction parts based on array count

Tags: php

I would like to create a function, which would automatically create data for my chart and I don't want to spam my source code with unused variables. My current max label count is 9 (so I don't need "count 10" and "count 11" condition yet), but it may be much more in the future, and I don't want to update my code everytime I create more labels...

Labels are stored in array `$labels` and every data from "count 2" should start with 0, and end with `$downloads['total']`. But from "count 3" I need to split `$downloads['total']`, because I need my `$chart_data` count to be equal to label count...

My current code may looks wierd, but it does exactly what I want:

```php
if (count($labels) == 1) {
    $chart_type = "bar";
    $chart_data =  "0";
}
else if (count($labels) == 2)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0," . $downloads['total']; // "0,x"
}
// from now, it should be done automatically based on labels count
else if (count($labels) == 3)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.5) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/2x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 4)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.33) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.66) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/3x,2/3x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 5)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.25) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.5) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.75) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/4x,2/4x,3/4x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 6)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.2) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.4) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.6) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.8) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/5x,2/5x,3/5x,4/5x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 7)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.166) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.333) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.5) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.666) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.833) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/6x,2/6x,3/6x,4/6x,5/6x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 8)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.143) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.286) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.429) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.571) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.714) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.857) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/7x,2/7x,3/7x,4/7x,5/7x,6/7x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 9)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.125) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.25) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.375) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.5) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.625) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.75) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.875) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/8x,2/8x,3/8x,4/8x,5/8x,6/8x,7/8x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 10)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.111) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.222) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.333) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.444) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.555) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.666) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.777) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.888) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/9x,2/9x,3/9x,4/9x,5/9x,6/9x,7/9x,8/9x,x"
}
else if (count($labels) == 11)  {
    $chart_type = "area";
    $chart_data =  "0,"  . round($downloads['total']*0.1) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.2) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.3) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.4) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.5) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.6) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.7) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.8) . "," . round($downloads['total']*0.9) . "," . $downloads['total']; // "0,1/10x,2/10x,3/10x,4/10x,5/10x,6/10x,7/10x,8/10x,9/10x,x"
}
```

Could anyone help me with that? Or there isn't any way, how to make it automatic/dynamic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect something like this [should be correct](https://3v4l.org/QkFB3). You're just looking to take the count of the array and use that as a denominator, and then set up a loop with the counter as a multiplier.

```php
$total      = $downloads["total"];
$count      = count($labels);
$chart_type = "area";
$chart_data = "0";
switch ($count) {
    case 1:
        $chart_type = "bar";
        break;
    case 2:
        $chart_data .=  ",$total";
        break;
    default:
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count - 2; $i++) {
            $chart_data .= "," . round($total / ($count - 1), 2) * $i;
        }
        $chart_data .= ",$total";
        break;
}
```

In future, providing sample data and expected output would make it easier to check for correctness.